# How to rescale displayed data in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a scatter plot chart which is able to filter my data. My problem is that when I filter and remove some data, the displayed data no longer fills up the container. I need to update the domain to the new extent (which excludes the removed data points).
Here is my code:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function draw(data, instrument) {

  var data = data[instrument];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
        d.year = +d.dyear;
        d.month = +d.month;
        d.day = +d.day;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, 1.2*d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
    .filter(function(d) { return d.day > 12; })
    .remove();

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
      .ticks(10));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(8));
    }

var dataset = d3.json("test.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  draw(data, "test_instrument");

});
```

Comment: do you need to keep the removed data in the original array?  or can you delete anything with day > 12 prior to loading/drawing

Comment: Well, later on I would like to make some buttons to display the data for the past week or month or year. So the removed data needs to stay in the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter the data, then reset the scale'domain based on the filtered dataset.  You may not need to remove circles that don't meet the criteria, but instead set the 'visibility' or 'opacity' instead (depending how many you want to hide)

```
let threshold = 12;

let filteredData = data.filter(function(d){ return d.day > threshold ; })
...
x.domain(d3.extent(filteredData , function(d) { return d.date; }));
...
svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    ...
    .style("visibility", function(d) { return d.day > threshold ? "visible": "hidden"; })
```